# Is it possible to create slug on homepage and how?

Tags: slug, homepage, seo

I'm wondering how can I create a slug on homepage for better SEO. I now have site translated in three different languages but my landing pages are like:

mydomain.com
mydomain.com/gr/
mydomain.com/bz/

I want to insert slug on a home page if it will help for better SEO. So my landing page would be like:

mydomain.com/my_work
mydomain.com/gr/my_work
mydomain.com/bz/my_work

Can somebody please tell me if this will improve my SEO and how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking would make those pages NOT be the home page, at least in WordPress's definition of the homepage.

If you want people to go straight to `/some-page` and not be able to access the root, then you would create a 301 redirect for this (but there will still technically be something on the root of the domain).

301 redirect example to redirect homepage to some page (this line would go in your `.htacess` file):

```
RewriteRule ^$ /some-page [L,R=301]
```

But, and answering your second question, this will not help SEO and I don't see why you would want to do this.

If you need to optimise for a particular phrase, then have a page for it and yes put the phrase in the slug of the page. But your home page is your home page. Refer to here for a better explanation of SEO related questions - webmasters.stackexchange.com.